# Editing a record in Access using Visual Basic Forms and SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I've been working on a simple project for school and I've come across a bit of a problem. I'm trying to edit a record in access from a visual basic form using SQL. usually this is pretty trivial but I simply cannot get this to work. I've tried rearranging quotes in almost everyway possible but to no avail. The error I'm receiving is as follows;

```
OleDbException was Unhandled, syntax error in UPDATE statement.
```

The line I'm having trouble with is below,

```
 Dim SQLSendEdit As String = "UPDATE StaffT SET Forename= '" & StaffForename     & "', Surname= '" & StaffSurname & "', DOB= '" & TxtDOBStaff.Text & "', Position= '" & TxtPositionStaff.Text & "', Address= '" & TxtAddressStaff.Text & "', Postcode= '" & TxtPostcodeStaff.Text & "', Tel= '" & TxtTelStaff.Text & "', Email= '" & TxtEmailStaff.Text & "', WHERE StaffID= '" & TxtIDStaff.Text & "'"
```

This is all one line in my solution so underscores aren't the problem here. I'm sure I'm missing something ridiculously obvious but I'd really appreciate some help. This is my first post so if I'm missing any important information or set something out wrong please feel free to let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Change `"', WHERE StaffID= '"` to `"' WHERE StaffID= '"`

Comment: One key technique to debugging this type of error is to print out the generated text (for instance to the immediate or output window) and inspect that.  It can be easier to spot.

Comment: Hi, HansUp, Thanks for the response. I've tried your suggestion and found that I still get the same error. Thank you for the help anyway.

Comment: C Perkins, you and I seem very like minded, I had already sent the output to a message box to see my results. Everything seems good but a very good suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Post the generated sql statement and your codeblock please

Answer (score -2):

Most likely, not all fields are text. Thus, perhaps *DOB* and *StaffID* are Date and Number respectively:

```
Dim SQLSendEdit As String = "UPDATE StaffT SET Forename= '" & StaffForename & "', Surname= '" & StaffSurname & "', DOB= #" & TxtDOBStaff.Text & "#, Position= '" & TxtPositionStaff.Text & "', Address= '" & TxtAddressStaff.Text & "', Postcode= '" & TxtPostcodeStaff.Text & "', Tel= '" & TxtTelStaff.Text & "', Email= '" & TxtEmailStaff.Text & "', WHERE StaffID= " & TxtIDStaff.Text & ""
```

Comment: That would not cause a 'syntax error'.  At most it would cause an error upon statement execution if there were a datatype conversion from text to, for example, a numeric field.  Otherwise it would perform automatic conversion from string to the field type.

Comment: @CPerkins: Automatic type conversion is in VBA.

Comment: The following update just executed without error and the string values were properly converted to the fields' respective data types (Date/Time, Integer, String, Currency):  `UPDATE Types SET Types.DDate = "11/1/18", Types.Num = "10", Types.Str = "String", Types.Cur = "3.24"`.  This was within Access itself, so perhaps the Access runtime leverages VBA.  I won't guarantee it will run via ODBC / OleDB, but either way I don't think it will be a syntax error since those interfaces also does not have knowledge of column types (without explicitly defining parameters).

Comment: Before I continue I'd just like to thank everyone for these brilliant responses, you are all really helping me out of a really tight spot here, I have changed the datatype of my DOB to short text to see if there is any difference. I'm still receiving the same error message. All field in the access database are now short text except for the StaffID which is an AutoNumber, so I can have a unique identifier for each record. I've heard that AutoNumber can be a problem wit SQL, am I better off Using Number and then creating a routine in vb that will assign records a unique number?

Comment: Dates should always be stored as Date, not text, no exceptions. But why not append the resulting (original) SQL to your question?